# Core Data in XCTests

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord, xctest

I am using Magical Record in application. 
I initialize

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
}
```

and application usually do some stuff while internet connection is present. 
I have tried to write an XCTest but I always receive SIGABRT:

```
   + (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_defaultContext
   {
      @synchronized(self) {
      NSAssert(MagicalRecordDefaultContext != nil, @"Default context is nil! Did you forget to initialize the Core Data Stack?");
      return MagicalRecordDefaultContext;
       }
   }
```

I have investigate it and could see that magical record successfully initialized in AppDelegate.

I even tried

```
   - (void)setUp {
       [super setUp];
       [MagicalRecord setDefaultModelFromClass:[self class]];
       [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];
   }

   - (void)tearDown {
       [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
       [super tearDown];
   }
```

But no luck. Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a few extra steps if your using Magic record. See [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/15/unit-testing-with-core-data/).

Comment: I am using cocoapods and Magical Record is included in test target in podfile

Comment: Thanks but I have seen this solution. It will work for testing core data methods itself, but I want to test another application functions not related with core data. And when I test them Magical Record loose it stack and turn default context to nil and then SIGABRT when other part of application try to call its methods

Comment: @dimak did you manage to fix this?. facing the same issue. Would be helpful if you can share

Comment: I have fixed this issue by calling
    [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
twice. Set test build variable and if it is test then I call migrate stack twice